# How can I calculate equation for this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $x = 1$, I need $ y=4$ and when $x = 15$ I need $y= 1$ and so on, it must get smaller with x gain but not go into minuses (as small as precision allows).

What I have tried:

a) $\frac{32}{x+7}$ close, but $y\neq 1$ at $x=15$

b) $\text{lerp}(4,1,1,15)$, but this has boundaries and goes into minuses

Any help appreciated

Comment: This is not clear.  You are effectively asking for a curve which passes through the points $(1,4)$ and $(15,1)$... but there are infinitely many such curves.  Some are squiggly, some are straight, some are complicated, some are not.  What additional properties or requirements do you have?  Do you have a specific form that you want the curve to fit?  E.g. $x$ and $y$ to be linearly correlated, inversely correlated, etc...

Comment: What you need is a non negative decreasing function of $x$. There are infinitely many functions, even if conditioned to pass from the points $(1,4)$ and $(15,1)$. Do you have any other constraints?

Comment: @JMoravitz Additional properties mentioned are monoton decreasing and it has to be non-negativ.

Comment: what is "lerp"?

Comment: Assuming you want them to be inversely correlated, as suggested by your attempt... you look like you might be wanting an equation of the form $y = \dfrac{a}{x+b}$.  Plugging in your two points ($4 = \frac{a}{1+b}$ and $1 = \frac{a}{15+b}$) and rearranging you have $4+4b = a$ and $15+b = a$ from which you can solve for $a$ and $b$ rather than just guess $32$ and $7$.

Comment: Linear interpolation

Comment: @JMoravitz can you write this as an answer. I will check it as an solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gathering comments:

Your attempt, you imply that you are looking for an equation of the form $y = \dfrac{a}{x+b}$

To emphasize... this is far from being the only curve satisfying your requirements, there being uncountably infinitely many curves satisfying the requirements.  That said, it does satisfy that it is a basic example and is easy to write and verify the properties of, etc...

Given that the curve should pass through $(1,4)$ and $(15,1)$ that implies that the equation $y=\dfrac{a}{x+b}$ should be true if these values were put in in place of $x$ and $y$.  Doing so we get that $4 = \dfrac{a}{1+b}$ and that $1=\dfrac{a}{15+b}$.

Rearranging, we have a system of two linear equations with two unknowns:

$$\begin{cases}4+4b=a\\15+b=a\end{cases}$$

We can now solve this using whatever methods you wish, e.g. matrices, substitution, elimination, etc... and in doing so we arrive at values for $a$ and $b$.

> $y = \dfrac{56/3}{x+11/3}$